# Spanning Tree interruption of service

Tags: networking

I'm about to enable Spanning Tree for the first time, but what I'm unclear on is mention of how the network will be unavailable occasionally when "a new device is added to the LAN".

Any device?  A computer powers on?  Sounds horrible.

What exactly is the network downtime with STP, and when exactly does it occur?  And is it for the whole switch?

Answer (score 0):

Assuming a default configuration, the network downtime with STP would be 30 seconds long. This 30 second time period commences from the time network switch detects a new device connected to it - basically when the computer turns on.

Another way of saying network downtime is that the Spanning-Tree Protocol is in the middle of moving the port from a blocking state to a forwarding state. Answering your other question, it is for just for the port and not for the switch.

That's STP in ultra basic terms, obviously there's more to it than that and it took me a while to understand. Would definitely recommend you check any online vids on it before turning on as it is intended for the quite specific purpose of loop elimination. In a consumer or home setup for example there wouldn't be a real need for this.